# Is there a Chronic-like natural language parser for time/date intervals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find a gem to parse, much like [Chronic](http://lee.jarvis.co/chronic/), recurrence intervals.  Things like `weekly` or `every three days` or `twice a year`.

Does anyone know if there is one?  Does Chronic do it and I'm just missing it?

Answer (score 1):

The [tickle gem](https://github.com/noctivityinc/tickle) is a parser for recurring events.

*Tickle is designed to be a compliment of Chronic and can interpret things such as “every 2 days, every Sunday, Sundays, Weekly, etc.”*

For example:

```
Tickle.parse('starting today and ending one week from now')
#=> {:next=>2010-05-10 22:30:00 -0400, :expression=>"day", :starting=>2010-05-09 22:30:00 -0400, :until=>2010-05-16 20:57:35 -0400}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any gems that offer this. You may be able to get somewhere by making use of Chronic's `Repeater` classes (`RepeaterDay`, `RepeaterWeek` etc).

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on these classes, but you can see some example uses in the **test** directory of Chronic's GitHub:
https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

-

What exactly were you hoping to receive back? The Time of the next occurrence, an Array of Time objects within a defined period, or something else?

Comment: Basically the time/date of the next occurrence.  I'll check out the examples you linked.  Thanks!